# Keep the most recent GROUPR of records in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up some data out of which I need to keep only the most recent but all of them, if they appear more than once. What confuses me is that the data are actually organised in "groups". I have a dataframe example below along with the comments that might make it clearer:

```
     method  year proteins  values
0      John  2017        A      10
1      John  2017        B      20
2      John  2018        A      30 # John's method in 2018 is most recent, keep this line and drop index 0 and1
3      Kate  2018        B      11
4      Kate  2018        C      22 # Kate's method appears only in 2018 so keep both lines (index 3 and 4)
5   Patrick  2017        A      90
6   Patrick  2018        A      80
7   Patrick  2018        B      85
8   Patrick  2018        C      70
9   Patrick  2019        A      60
10  Patrick  2019        C      50 # Patrick's method in 2019 is the most recent of Patrick's so keep index 9 and 10 only
```

So the desired output dataframe is irrelevant of the proteins that are measured but all the measured proteins should be included:

```
     method  year proteins  values
0      John  2018        A      30
1      Kate  2018        B      11
2      Kate  2018        C      22
3   Patrick  2019        A      60
4   Patrick  2019        C      50
```

Hope this is clear. I have tried something like this `my_df.sort_values('year').drop_duplicates('method', keep='last')` but it gives a wrong output. Any ideas? **Thank you!**

*PS: To replicate my initial df, you can copy the below lines:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

methodology=["John", "John", "John", "Kate", "Kate", "Patrick", "Patrick", "Patrick", "Patrick", "Patrick", "Patrick"]
year_pract=[2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019]
proteins=['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']
values=[10, 20, 30, 11, 22, 90, 80, 85, 70, 60, 50]
my_df=pd.DataFrame(zip(methodology,year,proteins,values), columns=['method','year','proteins','values'])

my_df['year']=my_df['year'].astype(str)
my_df['year']=pd.to_datetime(my_df['year'], format='%Y') # the format never works for me and this is why I add the line below
my_df['year']=my_df['year'].dt.year
```

Comment: No need for your PS for replicating your dataframe — we may use `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because duplicates is necessary use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `max` and compare by original column `year` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = my_df[my_df['year'].eq(my_df.groupby('method')['year'].transform('max'))]
print (df)

       method  year proteins  values
2        John  2018        A      30
3        Kate  2018        B      11
4        Kate  2018        C      22
9   Patrick's  2019        A      60
10  Patrick's  2019        C      50
```

Comment: thanks! Your answers are always food for thought, they bring up something I have never come across before or learnt by any course. Need to work on this ```transform``` and understand this ```equal```.